# React: inline if condition then display this div

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I can a react component which is based on the const.

```
const MyComp = (prop) => ... etc
```

In it I have some JSX:

```
<div id="myDiv">
        Stuff Here
</div>
```

I have a prop which is currently true called myprop.

So I want to add a condition the myDiv ... for example:

```
<div id="myDiv" {if myprop === true}>
        Stuff Here
</div>
```

So that the div will show only if the prop is true.

How do I do this in React?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then this should be achievable with the following JSX syntax:

```
{ (myprop === true) && <div id="myDiv">
        Stuff Here
   </div>
}
```

To summarize what is happening, this is effectively an expression that says, "if myprop === true" then "render the div"

Answer (score 3):

As @DacreDenny said but I can short it further like

```
{myprop && <div id="myDiv">Stuff Here</div>}
```